# Javascript Pac-Man collision detection

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Background info: I'm a beginner with Canvas, javascript, and jQuery, and overall game development. This is my first non-text game.

I have been working on this problem for a couple of days, and have hit 2 walls, of which I believe are connected. I'll describe the problems here, then give you the code;

1. When I draw the tiles onto the canvas, the board seems to be mirrored. I'm not sure why this is, but I can't seem to fix it.
2. I have mapped out the available routes for my character to go, but collision detection only works going up and down, but not going left and right.

Here's the code:

```
var TILE_WIDTH = 32, TILE_HEIGHT = 32, TICK_SPEED = 1000/30;
var playerimg = new Image(), ghostimg = new Image(), walkableimg = new Image(), wallimg = new Image(); 

playerimg.src = "player.png";
ghostimg.src = "ghost.png";
walkableimg.src = "walkable.png";
wallimg.src = "wall.png";


var map = [
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]



]

var spawnx = 128, spawny = 128;


var player = {direction: "right",image: playerimg, x:spawnx, y: spawny, xdir: spawnx, ydir: spawny}, ghost = {image:ghostimg, x:128 , y:128}, wall = {walkable: false,image: wallimg}, walkable = {walkable: true, image: walkableimg}; 


function main(){
    setInterval(

        function(){

            tick();
        }, TICK_SPEED)

}


function collisionDetect(direction){
    if(direction = "up" && map[(player.ydir/32)][(player.xdir/32)] == 0){
        player.y = player.ydir; //up    
        console.log("moved up");


    } else if(direction = "down" && map[(player.ydir/32)][(player.xdir32)] == 0){
        player.y = player.ydir; //down
        console.log("moved down");


    } else if(direction = "left" && map[player.ydir/32][(player.xdir/32)] == 0){
        player.x = player.xdir; //left
        console.log("moved left");

    } else if(direction = "right" && map[player.ydir/32][(player.xdir/32)] == 0){
        player.x = player.xdir; //right
        console.log("moved right ");
    } 

    player.xdir = player.x;
    player.ydir = player.y;
}

function solidDetect(block){

}



function render(){
    var field = document.getElementById("draw");
    var ctx = field.getContext("2d");
    renderField();
    renderPlayer();

}  

function renderPlayer(){
    var field = document.getElementById("draw");
    var ctx = field.getContext("2d");
    console.log(player.x,player.y,player.xdir,player.ydir);
    ctx.drawImage(player.image,player.x,player.y);
    ctx.rect(player.x,player.y,10,10);
    ctx.stroke();
}

function renderField(){
    var field = document.getElementById("draw");
    var ctx = field.getContext("2d");

    for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j<20; j++){

                if(map[i][j] == 1){
                    ctx.drawImage(wall.image,TILE_HEIGHT*i,TILE_HEIGHT*j);

                } else if(map[i][j] == 0){
                    ctx.drawImage(walkable.image,TILE_HEIGHT*i,TILE_HEIGHT*j);

                }



        }
    }
}

function tick(){

    render();

}





//key listener



$(document).keypress(function (eventObject) {
        var key = eventObject.keyCode;
        console.log(key);

        if (key == 115) {
        // up arrow
        console.log("Key pressed");
        player.ydir += 32;
        player.direction = "up";
        collisionDetect(player.direction);
        }
        else if (key == 119) {
            // down arrow
            console.log("Key pressed");
            player.ydir -= 32;
            player.direction = "down";
            collisionDetect(player.direction);
        }
        else if (key == 97) {
           // left arrow
           console.log("Key pressed");
           player.xdir -= 32;
           player.direction = "left";
           collisionDetect(player.direction);
        }
        else if (key == 100) {
           // right arrow
           console.log("Key pressed");
           player.xdir += 32;
           player.direction = "right";
           collisionDetect(player.direction);
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
})




main();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand what you mean by the board being mirrored. Whatever `map` contains gets rendered on my screen.

---

First of all, canvas width and height should be manually assigned:

```
function render(){
    var field = document.getElementById("draw");
    var ctx = field.getContext("2d");
    field.height = TILE_HEIGHT*map.length;
    field.width = TILE_WIDTH*map[0].length;
    renderField();
    renderPlayer();
}
```

---

I updated your key detection function to register arrow keys (`onkeydown` has to be used). Keep in mind that `y` coordinate is calculated from top left corner in Canvas.

```
window.onkeydown = function (eventObject) {
    var key = eventObject.keyCode;
    if (key == 38) {
        // up arrow
        console.log("Key pressed");
        player.ydir -= 32;
        player.direction = "up";
        collisionDetect(player.direction);
    }
    else if (key == 40) {
        // down arrow
        console.log("Key pressed");
        player.ydir += 32;
        player.direction = "down";
        collisionDetect(player.direction);
    }
    else if (key == 37) {
       // left arrow
       console.log("Key pressed");
       player.xdir -= 32;
       player.direction = "left";
       collisionDetect(player.direction);
    }
    else if (key == 39) {
       // right arrow
       console.log("Key pressed");
       player.xdir += 32;
       player.direction = "right";
       collisionDetect(player.direction);
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
};
```

---

You have two errors in `collisionDetect` function:

1. Assignment instead of comparison `if(direction = "up" &&...)`
2. Missing the division operator for down direction `(player.xdir32)`

Here is the fixed function:

```
function collisionDetect(direction){

    if(direction == "up" && map[(player.ydir/32)][(player.xdir/32)] == 0){
        player.y = player.ydir; //up    
        console.log("moved up");


    } else if(direction == "down" && map[(player.ydir/32)][(player.xdir/32)] == 0){
        player.y = player.ydir; //down
        console.log("moved down");


    } else if(direction == "left" && map[player.ydir/32][(player.xdir/32)] == 0){
        player.x = player.xdir; //left
        console.log("moved left");

    } else if(direction == "right" && map[player.ydir/32][(player.xdir/32)] == 0){
        player.x = player.xdir; //right
        console.log("moved right ");
    } 

    player.xdir = player.x;
    player.ydir = player.y;
}
```

And voilà! Movement and wall collisions work in all directions.

Comment: Thank you so much! However, could you add something in the map, and render that? When I render it, it seems to be mirrored, but the edges are fine. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle replicating your problem.